# Specific Ask & Discuss Widget / App does not work on my custom Masterpage

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, master-pages, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-apps

I've created a **custom** Masterpage, and one of my apps (an ask & discuss widget) does not work with it. All other widgets and apps work perfectly.

I tried checking if it was an issue with the coding in my master-page by removing my JavaScript and my CSS. Unfortunately this did not work. I noticed the app only works with the pre-installed `seattle.html`. I then duplicated `seattle.html`, `seattle2.html` and checked if the app works with it. Did not work.

What is going on?

Against my better judgement, I tried editing the original `seattle.html` by adding "Hello World" in the yellow div box that acts as a dynamic content placeholder. I saved it. The "Hello world" managed to cause the app stop working. I tried restoring to a previous version of `seattle.html` unfortunately, it didn't work.

This seems to be a custom Ask & Discuss web app that allows users to ask questions and then vote for their favorite answers (similar to Stack Exchange). It is still linked to a list, but the view is much more dynamic than your standard Out of Box Discussion Board available in SharePoint. I unfortunately cannot get support from the original installer.

[The view I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr0uN.png)
vs:

[The view I should get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioz1C.png)
**Can I get tips on what to look for in the code that may help me fix my issue?**

Comment: not sure but it seems that there are some text encoding issues.
which editor are you trying to change the master page?
Try using Notepad with UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Hi @shreyastigdi - I am using sharepoint designer...